# Self Study Inversion Formula Characteric Function

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning, characteristic-functions

Given the characteristic function:

$$
\varphi_X(t) = \frac{e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}}{1 + it}
$$

i am supposed to describe the corresponding distribution. By the inversion THM, we know that:

$$
f_X(x) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\pm T} e^{-itx} \varphi_X(t)dt = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\pm \infty} e^{-itx} \frac{e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}}{1 + it} dt = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\pm T} \frac{e^{\frac{-2itx-t^2}{2}}}{1 + it} dt
$$

Here I am stuck. I don't know how to integrate that. U-sub did not work.

Another approach that i was considering is to think of this as a transformation problem:

$$
\varphi_X(t)(1 + it) = e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}
$$

which is the characteristic function of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Do you insist in the inversion formula? A (dirty) trick might be more helpful.

Comment: Dirty trick sounds great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, your "another approach" is almost what I had in mind:
Assume we have a nice (differentiable) density function $f(x)$ with
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)\,e^{itx}\,dx=\frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{1+it},$$ with
$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$. Then, by partial integration, we have
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f'(x)\,e^{itx}\,dx=-it\,\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)\,e^{itx}\,dx,$$ i.e.
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}(f(x)-f'(x))\,e^{itx}\,dx=(1+it)\,\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)\,e^{itx}\,dx=e^{-t^2/2}.$$
Thus, we must have $$f(x)-f'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,e^{-x^2/2}\tag1.$$
Multiplying (1) by $e^{-x}$ gives
$$(f(x)-f'(x))\,e^{-x}=-\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)\,\,e^{-x})=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,e^{-x^2/2-x}=\frac{e^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,e^{-(x+1)^2/2},$$
and integrating, we see that
$$f(x)\,e^{-x}=C-\frac{e^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\int^x_{-\infty}e^{-(u+1)^2/2}\,du=C-e^{1/2}\,\Phi(x+1),$$ where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. The integration constant $C$ can be determined from $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, we must have $C=e^{1/2}$, and thus
$$f(x)=e^{1/2}\,e^x\,(1-\Phi(x+1)).$$ It's clear that this $f(x)$ has all those nice properties, so our derivation is justified. Integrating (1), we can also obtain the cdf:
$$F(x)=f(x)+\Phi(x)=e^{1/2}\,e^x\,(1-\Phi(x+1))+\Phi(x).$$

Comment: wow. just one question: why do you have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x) = 0$?

Comment: For $x\to-\infty$: because $e^x$ has limit $0$. For $x\to\infty$: because $\Phi(x+1/2)$ approaches $1$ very quickly.

Comment: I think this could be wrong

Comment: @Snoop Thank you for pointing that out! Is it ok, now?

Comment: @wasn'tme yes it seems it's working now

Comment: I don't understand the step from (1) to $f(x) = e^{1/2}e^x....$. Yes, if you multiply the rhs of (1) with $e^{-x}$ and integrate you obtain $\Phi(x+1)$. This i can reproduce. Can you explain the next step? Waht is C?

Comment: $C$ is an integration constant, since there is more than one function with a certain derivative. In differential equations, we choose the right value from initial conditions or boundary conditions, usually. In this case, we choose $C$ so that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: no sry, can't follow. So you have: $f e^{-x} - f' e^{-x} =\frac{e^{-(x^2/2 + x)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and then integrage: $\int f e^{-x} - \int f' e^{-x} = \int \frac{e^{-(x^2/2 + x)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ How do you go from here to: $f e^{-x} = C - \int \frac{e^{-(x^2/2 + x)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: ok, that is beautiful. yes of course, it's a differential equation! oh, man i never would have thought about that. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It is not hard to see that the CF in OP is the CF of the random variable $X-Y/2$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \chi^2(2) $ where $X,Y$ are independent
$$E[e^{it(X-Y/2)}]=E[e^{itX}]E[e^{-itY/2}]=e^{-t^2/2}(1-2i(-t/2))^{-1}=e^{-t^2/2}(1+it)^{-1}$$

Also, note that $-Y/2\sim -\Gamma(1,1)$ where $-\Gamma$ is a Gamma distribution on the negative line. Therefore we can compute the density explicitly by convolution:
$$\begin{aligned}\int_\mathbb{R}f_{-\Gamma (1,1)}(y)f_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(x-y)dy&=\int_{(-\infty,0]}e^{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x-y)^2/2}dy=\\
&=\frac{e^{y+1/2}}{2}\bigg(1-\textrm{erf}\bigg(\frac{y+1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\bigg)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: That's a very good answer, showing the structure of that distribution.

Comment: can you add one more step between $\int_{(-\infty, 0]}e^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x-y)^2/2}dy$? I don't see how the $x$'s disappear by integrating over $y$.

Comment: @user2550228 yes I used $y$ as the variable instead of $x$ (it's a typo). The pdf is

$$\frac{e^{x+1/2}}{2}\bigg(1-\textrm{erf}\bigg(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\bigg)$$